# Keyboard keys combination emulator

Tags: keyboard, hotkeys, emulator, transform

Is there any program who can emulate certain keystrokes and "transforms into other"?

For example, if I press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>, I want the computer to interpret it as <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> (just an example).

Answer (score 2):

You can do that and more with [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/). You can create [hotkeys](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm) and [remap](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/misc/Remap.htm) keys and buttons on your keyboard.

Comment: Hmm, I knew that you could have a key perform something else, but I didn’t expect that you could actually remap it so that the original key is still available; for example, you can swap a & b such that pressing ‘a’ gives ‘b’ and vice-versa: `a::b` & `b::a`. (I *do* still wonder if it creates a cyclic loop though, eg `void a(){b();} void b(){a();}`.)

Comment: Great. I knew about AutoHOtKey but didn´t know he could do that. Many thanks.

Comment: Could you give some examples? I want to Shift+UP Arrow to be transformed into NUMPAD8 for example

Comment: I am not proficient in Autohotkey and I suggest you ask another question for your above example with _autohotkey_ tag.